# Automated French/Italian/German to IPA transcription

Tags: phonetics, computational-linguistics, ipa, transcription, tools

I'm looking for a website or software that will take text written in a source language and produce a transcription in IPA.  The languages I am interested in are French, Italian and German, but if you know resources for other languages I would be happy to know.

For example, [English Phonetic Transcription](http://upodn.com) does English - IPA for free. Here's a sample of their transcription.

> All that glitters is not gold.
>
> ɒl ðæt glɪtərz ɪz nɑt gold.

I'm looking for a tool like this. If you're wondering why one would need such a tool, besides the obvious application of helping people learning a new language, it's also useful to singers/actors who have to perform in a foreign language.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[The open source eSpeak program](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) can do this:

```
espeak -v lang --ipa "text goes here"
```

where lang is:

- `fr` for French
- `it` for Italian
- `de` for German

It is not 100% accurate in pronunciation in all cases, but will speak out the pronunciations.

You can also use Kirshenbaum-like ASCII IPA:

```
espeak -v lang --ipa "[[orthographic text you want transcribed to IPA goes here]]"
```

If you use `-x` instead of `--ipa` you get the phonemes in the format that espeak accepts.

Comment: `espeak` supports a number of other languages (see `espeak --voices`), but one should be aware that not all can be considered as reliable, according to [the documentation](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/languages.html).

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer?  You asked for a program to go from audio to IPA transcription.  This goes from text to audio, and the text is not IPA.

Comment: The question is asking for *text in the source language* (not audio) to IPA, which is what this does. The `--ipa` option prints out the IPA transcription of what is being spoken. You can use `-q` if you don't want the audio and just want the IPA.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, it doesn't produce a transcription in IPA, like "English Phonetic Transcription" does.

Comment: Quidam: How so? `espeak -v en --ipa "foot strut"` results in `fˈʊt stɹˈʌt` which is valid IPA. It looks like "English Phonetic Transcription" is using US English (`-v en-us`), so that would produce `ˈɔːl ðæt ɡlˈɪɾɚz ɪz nˌɑːt ɡˈoʊld`. The differences then are either accent specific, quality differences (e.g. `t` vs `ɾ`, i.e. a "tapped T"), or transcription variants (e.g. `ər` vs `ɚ`). If you want an exact match you would need to modify the espeak phonemes or use sed (or other find/replace tool) to modify the phonemes to how you want them transcribed.

Answer (score 7):

I happend to find this: [EasyPronunciation.com](http://project-modelino.com/french-phonetic-transcription-converter.php)

Works okay for French, but it goofs up on some words, so watch out. Looks like English, Spanish and Chinese are also available there.

Here's something for German: [Donnerstag](http://familientagebuch.de/rainer/2007/38.html#4)

Comment: I was using this site but it limits the amount of transcriptions for some reason. I did not know it goofs up on some words, thanks for the heads up

Comment: @GuiImamura Not "for some reason", it's a premium service. If you aren't registered, you can submit a text per hour, it also limits the maximum size of the text.

Comment: I upvote this, it answers better to the question than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [IPANow](http://www.ipanow.com/index.html)? It does IPA transcriptions for Latin, Italian, German, and French.

Comment: English is free, French, Italian, German and Latin requires a payment.

Answer (score 2):

- For French: https://tophonetics.com

Languages: English, Español, **Français**, Português, 日本語, 中文, Русский

No Italian or German IPA

- For German: http://tom.brondsted.dk/text2phoneme

Languages: Danish, English, **German**.

- For Italian:

-> You can use Wordreference.com, for instance: https://www.wordreference.com/iten/ampio:  > [ˈampjo]

It should give IPA for the language in which it translates, so probably (needs to be checked one by one, I didn't.):
Español, **Français**, **Italiano**, Português, Català, **Deutsch**, Svenska, Nederlands, Русский, Polski, Română, Čeština, Ελληνικά, Türkçe, 英汉词典, 英和辞書,영-한 사전 قاموس إنجليزي , عربي

-> EasyPronounciation.com added Italian (you need to register to bypass the hourly limit, it's only one text per hour.), so, it has now:

**German** (with or without stress), English, Cantonese, Chinese, Spanish, **French**, **Italian**, Japanese, Persan, Russian (with or without stress).

-> https://www.ipasource.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=italian&order=relevance&dir=desc
It gives transcription of texts, but you cannot submit your own one in the free version.

It has English, **French**, **Italian**, **German**, Spanish, Latin, and maybe a few other ones.

- For all languages,
  You can also use the Wiktionary, it's often accurate (most of the time).

Comment: Note, that tophonetics.com only does English transcription, the languages listed only concern an interface of the website.