# eSpeak - Use transformation to IPA in Windows

Tags: ipa, transcription

[eSpeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) is capable of transforming text to IPA, as also mentioned in [this](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/325/automated-french-italian-german-to-ipa-transcription?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) question.

I want to use the same feature in its Windows version. Is it possible?

I have tried a lot, but failed.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly what you failed to do. Assuming that you have the program installed and located the command-line exe, you opened a command window and ran the program as e.g. espeak --phonout="test.txt" --ipa "this is my text", you should get the IPA string " ðɪs ɪz maɪ tˈɛkst" in test.txt. If you run the program in the Program Files (x86) directory where espeak is installed and write to that diretory, you have to run under an admin command window, in order to also write to the directory where you're running the program (I forgot this and wasted some time remembering this). Maybe clarify what worked and what didn't.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I made some progress, although the instruction above does not work as expected. Right now, I cannot write to "test.txt", and if I choose to get the output in the command line, then the characters used seem wrong.

Comment: IPA typed to a command window does look strange: graphics junk with normal letters. In my text, you should see recognizable "kst" at the end. If you do this: echo Hello word > crud.txt and the system says Access is denied, you're in a protected directory.